# Streaming protocols

Tags: streaming, protocols, broadcasting

I know all about the streaming protocols and what they are good for. But what confuses me is the protocols the video stream is encoded. Because the encoders use usually RTMP or RTSP protocols and then it is up to the service provider or decoder how the video/stream is delivered (in which protocol: HLS, WebRTC, HDS, MPED-DASH etc).

So it might be a silly question but is there a way to change the encoding protocols from RTMP or RTSP? When I record a video/live-stream with a software. Right now I am using OBS. And my main goal is findign a solution how to stream one-to-many with as low latency as possible (>2s).

---

Also as far as I know the difference between RTSP and RTMP is one uses iOs and the other Windows OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So it might be a silly question but is there a way to change the encoding protocols from RTMP or RTSP? When I record a video/live-stream with a software. Right now I am using OBS. And my main goal is

Yes. There are many (many, many) streaming servers on the market. nginx, red5, wowza, etc.

> Also as far as I know the difference between RTSP and RTMP is one uses iOs and the other Windows OS.

No. protocols and operating systems are not related at all. Any OS can utilize any protocol. Web browsers are limited to just a few.

> When I record a video/live-stream with a software. Right now I am using OBS. And my main goal is findign a solution how to stream one-to-many with as low latency as possible (>2s).

This is a HUGE question, that really can not be answered on stack overflow. `one-to-many`; is many 10 or 1000 or 1000000, They are different answers. Does it need to work on web or not (different answers). What does your infrastructure look like, what is your operation budget. Are users located global, or geographically centralized? All this would change the answer. And some of those answer may be that your problem is not practical. for example >2s 100000 users globally on web would be very expensive.

Comment: The audience wouldn't be big - around 500 at max and it would be all around the world.